# How to continue sending email using Transport (javax.mail) even some "recipients" are not even email addresses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am using Transport (javax.mail) to send emails to a list of recipients.

I found that if I set `mail.smtp.sendpartial=true`, even if some recipients don't exist, which means they are in valid email format but the addresses don't exsit such as a random string of "asjkdgh@sdawaec.com", the valid ones will still receive the emails.

However, if some recipients are not even in valid email format, for example "abcd", then the whole list including the valid one will be discarded entirely.

I am wondering how to solve it? How to continue the sending even if there are recipients such as "abcd"?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you filter the list in your code, so you're only passing valid emails to the mail library?

Comment: Are you sure that your `mail.smtp.sendpartial=true` is really taken into consideration? What you describe is [the default behaviour (`false`) according to the doc](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.sendpartial).

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica I testes it. If it is set to `false`, the "asjkdgh@sdawaec.com" will stop the sending, but it is "true", then valid emails will receive emails. But no matter what, an email of "abcd" will stop the sending.

Comment: @nanofarad I could, but I am just wondering if there is an automatical way to do that.